# Typescript errors in node_modules package with "export * as" syntax

Tags: node.js, typescript

I'm working on a Typescript NodeJS project that uses multiple Google Cloud client libraries.
I want to use ES6 imports for these client libraries so I can use Intellisense in VS Code.
However, when I use ES6 imports I get the following issues when trying to compile Typescript:

> ````
> TS1005: 'from' expected.
>
> 119 export * as protobufMinimal from 'protobufjs/minimal';
>              ~~
>
> node_modules/google-gax/build/src/fallback.d.ts:119:13 - error TS1005:
> ';' expected.
>
> 119 export * as protobufMinimal from 'protobufjs/minimal';
>                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
> node_modules/google-gax/build/src/fallback.d.ts:119:29 - error TS1005:
> ';' expected.
>
> 119 export * as protobufMinimal from 'protobufjs/minimal';
>                                 ~~~~
>
> node_modules/google-gax/build/src/fallback.d.ts:119:34 - error TS1005:
> ';' expected.
>
> 119 export * as protobufMinimal from 'protobufjs/minimal';
>                                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
> node_modules/google-gax/build/src/index.d.ts:47:10 - error TS1005:
> 'from' expected.
>
> 47 export * as protobufMinimal from 'protobufjs/minimal';
>             ~~
>
> node_modules/google-gax/build/src/index.d.ts:47:13 - error TS1005: ';'
> expected.
>
> 47 export * as protobufMinimal from 'protobufjs/minimal';
>                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
> node_modules/google-gax/build/src/index.d.ts:47:29 - error TS1005: ';'
> expected.
>
> 47 export * as protobufMinimal from 'protobufjs/minimal';
>                                ~~~~
>
> node_modules/google-gax/build/src/index.d.ts:47:34 - error TS1005: ';'
> expected.
>
> 47 export * as protobufMinimal from 'protobufjs/minimal';
>                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
>
> Found 8 errors. ```
> ````

Are there any changes I need to make to my `tsconfig` to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: What version of Typescript are you running ? has mention [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#export-all-as-x), it required typescript 3.8. Maybe you Vscode is configured to an older version.

Comment: I believe you need to set `"esModuleInterop": true` in `tsconfig.json`

Comment: I'm running Typescript 3.9.7 and I have the `esModuleInterop` option set to true in my config

Comment: @NielsKersic have you manage to fix that?

Comment: @AntonPegov Never managed to fix it

Comment: Oh, we fixed it by upgrading project's typescript version )

Comment: what version did you install?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're seeing this in your GCloud builds the fix in my case was updating Typescript from 3.7.2 to 4.1.3 - from my understanding any version 3.9+ should work fine.

Comment: I have google-gax files in my cloud-functions folder with typescript  "version": "3.9.10", but still I am having the same build errors. Any help?